# Include ajax comments in index in rails 4

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, comments

I have ajax comments in my rails app and it all works in the posts show but I'd like to add the form to render the comments in the index page.

I'm using sorl when rendering the index page and I tried to include comments in the post model like this:

```
searchable(:include => :comments) do

  code....

end
```

but that doesn't render the comments below the posts in the index page, even though I have this in the view

```
 <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment',:collection => @comments,  :as => :comment %>
```

So to help you understand, here is all the code:

**_post.html.erb:**

```
<%= simple_form_for [post, Comment.new], :url => comments_path,  :remote => true do |f| %>

  <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:small) %> 
  <%= f.input :body, placeholder: 'write a comment...', :input_html => { :rows => "1"}, :label => false %>

   //the below two lines do not work, the commentable_id is 0 and commentable_type is blank
   //post.comments.commentable_id doesn't work either
  <%= f.input :commentable_id, :as => :hidden, :value => Comment.new.commentable_id  %> 
  <%= f.input :commentable_type, :as => :hidden, :value => Comment.new.commentable_type %>

   <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', :id => 'commentsend') do %>
     <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
   <% end %>

  <% end %>

   <%= render :partial => 'comments/comment',:collection => @comments,  :as => :comment %>
```

**Posts_controller:**

def index

```
    @user_count = User.where(:school => current_user.school).count

    @blub_count = Post.where(:category => "status").where(:school => current_user.school).count

    @items_count = Post.where(:school => current_user.school).where.not( :category => "status").count


    @search = Post.search(:include => :comments) do #Post.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      with(:school, current_user.school)
      paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 20 
      order_by(:updated_at, :desc)  
       end

    @posts = @search.results 




    respond_to do |format|
       format.js
      format.html
    end



  end






   def show

    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comments = @post.comment_threads.order('created_at desc')
    @new_comment = Comment.build_from(@post, current_user, "")


  end
```

**comments_controller:**

```
def create
    @comment_hash = params[:comment]
    @obj = @comment_hash[:commentable_type].constantize.find(@comment_hash[:commentable_id])
    # Not implemented: check to see whether the user has permission to create a comment on this object
    @comment = Comment.build_from(@obj, current_user.id, @comment_hash[:body])
    if @comment.save
      render :partial => "comments/comment", :locals => { :comment => @comment }, :layout => false, :status => :created
    else
      render :js => "alert('error saving comment');"
    end
  end
```

**comments model:**

```
acts_as_nested_set :scope => [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]

  validates :body, :presence => true
  #validates :user, :presence => true

  # NOTE: install the acts_as_votable plugin if you
  # want user to vote on the quality of comments.
  #acts_as_votable

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  # NOTE: Comments belong to a user
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  # Helper class method that allows you to build a comment
  # by passing a commentable object, a user_id, and comment text
  # example in readme
  def self.build_from(obj, user_id, comment)
    new \
      :commentable => obj,
      :body        => comment,
      :user_id     => user_id
  end

  #helper method to check if a comment has children
  def has_children?
    self.children.any?
  end

  # Helper class method to lookup all comments assigned
  # to all commentable types for a given user.
  scope :find_comments_by_user, lambda { |user|
    where(:user_id => user.id).order('created_at DESC')
  }

  # Helper class method to look up all comments for
  # commentable class name and commentable id.
  scope :find_comments_for_commentable, lambda { |commentable_str, commentable_id|
    where(:commentable_type => commentable_str.to_s, :commentable_id => commentable_id).order('created_at DESC')
  }

  # Helper class method to look up a commentable object
  # given the commentable class name and id
  def self.find_commentable(commentable_str, commentable_id)
    commentable_str.constantize.find(commentable_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments form shoudl be like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for Comment.build_from(post, current_user, ""), :url => comments_path,   :remote => true do |f| %>
```

I have to assign the comment the current post ID(commentable_id) and current user id for commentable_type to build the comment

in the view, to render the comments I used

```
<%= render post.comment_threads.order('created_at desc') %>
```

the only issue is the the render is ignoring the div